# How to check - $scope.students = []; - in JavaScript - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the complete code:

When page is loaded, then I am getting "Hello undefined - undefined" - which I do NOT want ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="peopleController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> FirstName </th>
                <th> LastName </th>
                <th> &nbsp; </th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
                <td> {{person.firstName}} </td>
                <td> {{person.lastName}} </td>
                <td> <input type="button" value="Select" ng-click="selectPerson($index)" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
        {{ sayHello() }}
    </div>
    <script>

        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

        myApp.controller('peopleController', function ($scope) {

            $scope.people = [ { firstName: 'F1', lastName: 'L1' },
                              { firstName: 'F2', lastName: 'L2' },
                              { firstName: 'F3', lastName: 'L3' },
                              { firstName: 'F4', lastName: 'L4' },
                              { firstName: 'F5', lastName: 'L5' }];

            $scope.selectedPerson = {};

            $scope.selectPerson = function(ind)
            {
                $scope.selectedPerson = $scope.people[ind];
            }

            $scope.sayHello = function() {
        if ($scope.selectedPerson !== "undefined")
        {
                    return "Hello " + $scope.selectedPerson.firstName + " - " + $scope.selectedPerson.lastName;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
            }

        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not want to check each and every property. Instead, I want to check whole entity.

```
$scope.selectedPerson = {};

if ($scope.selectedPerson !== "undefined") // This is the entity check (Not working properly)
```

Comment: `if ($scope.students.length>0)`;

Comment: This is NOT working. Please find the complete code, which I have provided. Let me know, your comments ...

Comment: I have solved it ... Thanks for your help !